# Java: Parse multiple String Date Time format into LocalDateTime/Date/Calender

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

I am trying to parse string date Time into `LocalDateTime` or `Date` in Java.
I may get the inputs Like `12/21/2020 12:12:12 PM`, `1/12/2020 2:6:8 PM`, `10/2/2020 10:50:8 AM`

I tried to use different types of patterns under `DateTimeFormatter` or `DateTimeFormatBuilder` Which Can Work. Brute force method [Where I am Hard coding different combination of pattern](https://repl.it/repls/WearableGratefulHashfunction). Here's the code copied from the link:

```java
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // many combinations
        final String DATE_FORMATS = "[MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a][M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss a]";
        DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_FORMATS);

        System.out.println(dateFormatter.parse("12/21/2020 11:12:12 AM"));
        System.out.println(dateFormatter.parse("1/12/2020 2:54:55 AM"));
    }
}
```

Is there any other solution as I don't have control over a input? Single pattern which,I can use in `Formatter` Instead of multiple combination ? Or Is it better to modify the input after receiving before parsing?

Comment: How can we tell you if there is a solution *different from the one you haven't shown here*? Please edit your question and add your version, thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you tried, what you'd expected and what happened instead!

Comment: Talk is cheap, show the code!

Comment: What do you mean by "brute force method"? The standard way to parse a `String` into one of the `java.time` classes is `DateTimeFormatter`. Please show a [mre] demonstrating the problem you're having.

Comment: I copied the code from your link into your question as questions should be self-contained.

Comment: As for your question, what sort of solution are you looking for? If you have multiple potential formats then you're going to need multiple patterns or a single pattern that can handle all the different patterns (if even possible). The better option is to control the input and require it to be a certain format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl;dr

`LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy h:m:s a");`
is sufficient for all of your datetime examples.

---

The following example is able to parse all of your sample datetime `String`s by using `LocalDateTime.parse` instead of `DateTimeFormatter.parse`, which are different:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String first = "12/21/2020 12:12:12 PM";
    String second = "1/12/2020 2:6:8 PM";
    String third = "10/2/2020 10:50:8 AM";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter
            .ofPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a][M/dd/yyyy h:m:s a][MM/d/yyyy HH:mm:s a]");

    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(first, dtf));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(second, dtf));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(third, dtf));
}
```

Have a look at the second / middle pattern used, it uses `h` (lower case) for hours instead of an `H` (upper case) because the AM/PM of day will be derived from a capital `H`, too and that would lead to a conflict in the second datetime sample `"1/12/2020 2:6:8 PM"` where 02:06:08 is considered AM, but is followed by PM in the pattern.

The output of my solution is this:

```
2020-12-21T12:12:12
2020-01-12T14:06:08
2020-10-02T10:50:08
```

which correctly parses the time to PM (14 = 02 PM).

**Note:**
Don't use this `DateTimeFormatter` for output  `LocalDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter)` because it would return all three formattings defined...
Very ugly: `10/02/2020 10:50:08 AM10/02/2020 10:50:8 AM10/2/2020 10:50:8 AM`

Comment: Pattern `DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[M/d/yyyy h:m:s a]");`  Works for all the different combination. If we Do `LocalDateTime.parse`

Comment: @Thilakraj OK, thanks, good to know. I hadn't checked just a single of the patterns, used all of them. Will edit that into the answer!

Answer (score 3):

I dealt with a similar problem, where I needed to parse a String to date without knowing the format in advance. I wrote an article about the idea and the implementation. Here is a quote from the article:

So the solution I came up with is to have a set of formats stored in property file, and when a String needs to be parsed the formats are read from a file and attempts to parse the String are made sequentially with each format until it is parsed successfully or until we run out of formats. The advantages of this solution are that if you discover a  valid String that was not parsed successfully, all you will need to do is to add new format to your properties file and no re-compilation and re-deployment is needed. Also this way you can set your priorities: say if US date format is preferable to  European one just place US formats first and only after the European ones. Also in java 8 the format strings allow for optional format sections denoted by '[]'. So several formats actually may be combined into a single one with optional sections. For example instead of

```
MM/dd/yyyy
MM-dd-yyyy
MM.dd.yyyy
```

you can just write

```
MM['/']['-']['.']dd['/']['-']['.']yyyy
```

Here is the link to the full [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)

Comment: @deHaar - Thank you so much. BTW I have some other articles on the same site. Also, if you could leave a short comment for the article I would appreciate it very much

Comment: I didn't find good words for a comment so far, but I liked using the platform *like*-function ;-)

Comment: While informative it doesn’t appear to me to be very relevant to the question asked.